# Render Preview vs Render Image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have created an animation scene. It's time to set up the stage lighting. The render preview shows a minimal set of lights. As I plan.

[image]

When rendering an image (F12), I see a completely different picture.

[image]

Before, I always thought that these views should be identical. I checked *Compositing*, *World Settings* under Shading. There is nothing. Everything is standard. Where can extra light come from? Blender version 3.6.2.

Comment: The views can be identical if everything is set to be identical. But if it doesn't it can have many different reasons which we can only guess without seeing the objects in your _Outliner_, the _Viewport Shading_ settings etc. For example, it could be you have light sources in your scene which are set to be hidden in the viewport, but are visible for rendering. Or in the _Viewport Shading_ options it could be that under _Lighting_ the _Scene Lights_ and _Scene World_ are disabled which would then use the _Material Preview_ lighting... hard to tell without knowing your settings or your file...

Comment: Yes please show your Viewport Shading and your Outliner

Comment: OK. Thank you. There was one extra lamp turned on for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex scenes with many objects require convenient and correct organization. All objects must be renamed and grouped according to similar characteristics in a collection. In this case, such misunderstandings will not arise. The final render of this scene can be seen at the link: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/eyPfUWDr7xw